# How to read all lines in socket (swift)

Tags: swift, sockets, swift2

I have problem to read lines. When server (server code in java) sent more than one line code, my secket can not read all lines.

**I used this library** https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket
and socket read method code:

```
private func sendRequest(data: String, client: TCPClient?) -> (String?) {
    // It use ufter connection
    if client != nil {
        // Send data  (WE MUST ADD TO SENDING MESSAGE '\n' )
        let (isSuccess, errorMessage) = client!.send(str: "\(data)\n")
        if isSuccess {
            // Read response data
            let data = client!.read(1024*10)
            if let d = data {
                // Create String from response data
                if let str = NSString(bytes: d, length: d.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {
                    return (data: str)
                } else {
                    return (data: nil)
                }
            } else {
                return (data: nil)
            }
        } else {
            print(errorMessage)
            return (data: nil)
        }
    } else {
        return (data: nil)
    }
}
```

I have changed like this : `let data = client!.read(1024*40)` but again can not read (received data large). it read some received data like this:

```
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
```

but not all. How to fix this. Please, advise me. Thanks

Comment: i don't know too much about SwiftSocket library, but you are better to read some manual there. generally, when you try to read some data from socket, there is no guaranty how much data are reading from the underlying socket in one bunch. the parameter of your read function is probably just the maximum size of data which you can read continuously.

Comment: I think its sending JSON message try the following. let JSONdata: AnyObject = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(Data!, options: .MutableContainers))   print(JSONdata)

Comment: @Karlos, received data is encrupted data. this code woked perfect but not lagre data

Comment: @user3441734, yes, it has maximum (1024*10)

Comment: Hey @Clever , I'm new to this socket thing in swift ....can you help me with it ???

Answer (score 1):

there is your responsibility to check what did you received and how to process all data received from your socket. try to check this simple example how to read line delimited text from network. you can easily adopt this code for use with your library, or use it as is if you have working socket handle ...

```
import Darwin

private var line = [UInt8]()
private var excess = [UInt8]()

private func readLine(inout lineBufer: [UInt8], inout excessBufer: [UInt8], var sockHandle: Int32, wait: Bool = true) -> Int{
    // (1) received bytes in one cycle and numbers of cycles to receive
    // whole line (line delimited text)
    var received = 0
    var i = 0

    // (2) clear the buffer for the extra bytes readed after the \n
    excessBufer.removeAll()
    var buffer = [UInt8](count: 64, repeatedValue: 0)

    // (3) read from network until at least one \n is found
    repeat {
        received = read(sockHandle, &buffer, buffer.count)

        if received == 0 {
            close(sockHandle)
            sockHandle = -1
            print("connection lost")
            return -1
        }

        if received < 0 {
            print("\treceived failed:", String.fromCString(strerror(errno))!)
            return -1
        }

        i = 0
        while i < received && buffer[i] != UInt8(ascii: "\n") { i++ }
        lineBufer.appendContentsOf(buffer[0..<i])
        // (4) now consume '\n'
        i++
        // (5) we have extra bytes for next line         received -i > 0
        if i < received {
            excessBufer.appendContentsOf(buffer[i..<received])
            break // from loop
        }
        // (6) if no extra bytes and no whole line, than received - i < 0 (-1)
        // if whole line and no extra bytes,        than received - i = 0
    } while i != received
    return received
}

// (1) prepare buffers
line.removeAll()
line.appendContentsOf(excess)

// (2) read line delimited text ( socket is you uderlying socket handle )
readLine(&line, excessBufer: &excess, sockHandle: socket)

// now your line buffer consist of one line ot text

// do something with the line and repeate the proces as you need .....

// (1) prepare buffers
line.removeAll()
line.appendContentsOf(excess)

// (2) read line delimited text
readLine(&line, excessBufer: &excess, sockHandle: socket)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the GitHub repository you mentioned, I'm under the impression that this is a relatively new and not well-supported project.  Yes, it may provide a somewhat simplified interface to sockets, but it is unknown how buggy it is and what its future is.  Instead of using it, one might be better off using well-supported Apple Objective-C frameworks.  Please see

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/CommonPitfalls/CommonPitfalls.html

It is fairly easy to use the Foundation framework with Swift.  Yes, you can definitely call POSIX C networking API from Swift, but that is more work and is not recommended in iOS, as it doesn't activate the cellular radio in the device, as explained in the aforementioned Apple articles.

Comment: I checked the github sources as well, it seems that the base is well done (at first sight). i agree with you, that the library is just torso, not the whole package, but the trouble of OP is that he didn't realize  the difference between one line of text and some bytes received from socket

Comment: Downvoted because the OP tagged his question for `swift` and NOT Objective-C.